# Why does my nose run like a faucet when I'm outside in blustery wet weather?

Tags: mucus-phlegm, environmental-climate, runny-nose, seasonal-allergies, weather

What about cold blustery wet weather makes my nose run like crazy? I've read online that it's because the air is dry... but I live in Vancouver and it's super damp here so I'm not sure that's why my nose runs like crazy when I'm outside walking in the wet and windy weather. Is it because of seasonal allergies?

When I'm inside it's not running at all... but outside, it's like flipping an "on" switch.

**How does blustery wet weather make one's nose runny?**